# Conditions on $A,B$ that are inherited by $A+B$.

Tags: general-topology

> Let $A,B$ be subsets of $\Bbb{R}$. Which of the following is false:
>
> 1. If $A,B$ are bounded, then so is $A+B$.
> 2. If $A,B$ are open, then so is $A+B$.
> 3. If $A,B$ are closed, then so is $A+B$.
> 4. If $A,B$ are connected, then so is $A+B$.

It seems to me that all four are true! Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried really proving all of those?

Comment: @LuizCordeiro- I mainly constructed examples. Lots of them!

Comment: It's hard to give a good hint without giving you the answer, but 3. is false.

Answer (score 0):

1,2,4 are true but 3 is false.

Comment: Could you give an example?

Comment: Hint: You can always write $1/n$ as $(n+1/n)+(-n)$.

Comment: 1. Generally if $A, B$ are bounded in a normed space then so is $A+B$

Comment: @LuizCordeiro- Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Hints:

1) True as $\mathbb{R}$ is a normed linear space and hence $triangle\ inequality$ holds so ...

2) True. For $x,y\in \mathbb{R}$ we have open balls $B',B''$ around $x,y$ respectively such that $B'\subset A$ and $B''\subset B$. Now you are translating $x$ by $y$. So with how much distance you need to translate one of the open ball so that the resulting ball lies in $A+B$ ?

3)  False. Consider the set $X=\{m+n\sqrt{2}\ \mid\ m,n\in \mathbb{Z}\}$. Note that $X=A+B$ where $A=\mathbb{Z}$ and $B=\mathbb{Z}\sqrt{2}$ both of which are closed. It can be shown that $X$ is dense in $\mathbb{R}$, thus $\bar{X}=\mathbb{R}\neq X$. Hence $X$ is not closed.

4) True. Since $A\times B$ is connected in $\mathbb{R}^2$, addition is a continuous function and continuous image of a connected set is connected. So can you identify $A+B$ as a continuous image of some function from $A\times B$ ?

Comment: *chuckles*  #4 was the exact argument I just used last semester on my qualifier exam, for that exact question.   @whee!